# Why does sed cause git to consider the entire file rewritten?

Tags: git, cygwin, sed

Using Cygwin on Win7x32, when I use `sed` to replace some values in a file, `git` then considers the entire file to be completely rewritten (i.e., 500 insertions, 500 deletions). What's going on here? Only one line in the file is actually changed, and the replacement value is the same length as the original. I'd expect `git` to recognize only the lines that changed. The only thing that seems to have changed at all is the inode and time values as read from `stat some/file.txt`. Is there a way to tell `git` to ignore any relevant changed values for the duration of my `sed` calls, or to tell `sed` to not change any values that cause `git` to see a file with entirely new content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't work with Windows much, but perhaps `sed` is changing your end-of-line markers.  The `file` command will tell you which text encoding is being used.  Also, you can run `cat -e` before and after you call `sed`; if the file is encoded for Windows each line will end with `^M`.

Comment: This looks like the culprit; before, the file is `ASCII C++ program text, with CRLF line terminators`, and after, `ASCII C++ program text`. I was under the impression that `sed` didn't do any sort of automagical conversions like that, being a "stream editor," but oh well.

Comment: Does cygwin have the `unix2dos` tool?  That'll put back the Windows end-of-line marker.

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up using. Just a little surprised after hearing so many good things about `sed`.

Comment: Using unix2dos helped, however somehow, now I have only replaced line ending in ^M, the rest is still LF.